# Laravel show username instead of id on edit profile

Tags: laravel

When the user has to edit their profile it shows the id like so [Click to see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73ilE.png)

that is not what I want. I want to replace it with the profile username and remove the edit part. I really hope someone is understanding what I'm asking for. let me show you what I am looking for something like this "localhost/lary/quickstart/public/profile/username"

here is what i have in my code

```
public function edit($id)
{

      $pro=Profile::find($id);
      return view('layouts.profileedit')->with('pro',$pro);


}

<a href="{{route('profile.edit',$use->id)}}" style="color:#F88B22;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

Comment: Post your `web.php` routes file. That's where you can get to define the URL structure

Comment: This what I am using for my routes Route::resource('profile','ProfileController'); so how am i going to do it there if i am using resources

Comment: Your photo is not being displayed, can you add the code of your view?

Comment: @Mirdrack  http://localhost/lary/quickstart/public/profile/21/edit

Comment: @Stephany.S123 you just send me the route of your local environment, I was talking about the code as you posted in your question and I'm not really sure what you are trying to do it but I suppose you should print the username member of your class in your html

Comment: its on the screen

Answer (score 1):

Change your **routes file** as follows:

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController', ['except' => ['edit']]);
Route::get('/profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@edit');
```

Then change your **ProfileController** as follows

```
public function edit($username)
{
      $pro=Profile::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
      return view('layouts.profileedit')->with('pro',$pro);
}
```

Comment: Ok I'll try and let you know if that works. Thank you

Comment: I am getting a blank page this what I am getting http://localhost/lary/quickstart/public/profile/%7B$username%7D  I notice that Its pointing to the show controller and there nothing there and that why I am getting the blank page and I am not geting the user name

Comment: Can I like hash the id instead because its not working. or something I just don't want people to edit other people stuff